# Finding highest values in each row in a data frame for python

Tags: python, pandas, ranking

I'd like to find the highest values in each row and return the column header for the value in python. For example, I'd like to find the top two in each row:

```
df =  
       A    B    C    D  
       5    9    8    2  
       4    1    2    3
```

I'd like my for my output to look like this:

```
df =        
       B    C  
       A    D
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are there numbers missing from the output? You might be looking for the `nlargest` method.

Comment: The output I'd like to show is the corresponding column header. So, 9 and 8 in the first row of the input are columns B and C. Hope this makes sense. I've messed around with the nlargest method but haven't figured it out yet. I may be doing it wrong though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to generate the `largest_n` values in each row of the dataframe.  I transposed the dataframe and then applied `nlargest` to each of the columns.  I used `.index.tolist()` to extract the desired `top_n` columns.  Finally, I transposed this result to get the dataframe back into the desired shape.

```
top_n = 2
>>> pd.DataFrame({n: df.T[col].nlargest(top_n).index.tolist() 
                  for n, col in enumerate(df.T)}).T
   0  1
0  B  C
1  A  D
```

Answer (score 12):

I decided to go with an alternative way: Apply the `pd.Series.nlargest()` function to each row.

**Path to Solution**

```
>>> df.apply(pd.Series.nlargest, axis=1, n=2)
     A    B    C    D
0  NaN  9.0  8.0  NaN
1  4.0  NaN  NaN  3.0
```

This gives us the highest values for each row, but keeps the original columns, resulting in ugly NaN values where a column is not everywhere part of the top n values. Actually, we want to receive the index of the `nlargest()` result.

```
>>> df.apply(lambda s, n: s.nlargest(n).index, axis=1, n=2)
0    Index(['B', 'C'], dtype='object')
1    Index(['A', 'D'], dtype='object')
dtype: object
```

Almost there. Only thing left is to convert the Index objects into Series.

**Solution**

```
df.apply(lambda s, n: pd.Series(s.nlargest(n).index), axis=1, n=2)
   0  1
0  B  C
1  A  D
```

Note that I'm not using the `Index.to_series()` function since I do **not** want to preserve the original index.