# Find 10 largest numbers in a row in csv file using python?

Tags: python, csv

Currently I am doing a sample work where I have a csv file look like this.
[image]

This csv file has 500 rows and 100 columns. I want to take 10 largest values from every row and save it in another csv file.
[image]

Like this picture from 1st row I want 10 largest values. And for the next rows they also give 10 largest values for every row. And I want to save the values in another csv file. 
How can I do it?
Can it be done by pandas? Thanks.

Comment: What did you search for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding highest values in each row in a data frame for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518634/finding-highest-values-in-each-row-in-a-data-frame-for-python)

Comment: Yeah almost, but I need to find the values in every rows and copy it in another csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .nlargest() for each row.

```
top_n = 10
for i in df.index[:2]:
    print(df.loc[i].nlargest(top_n))
```

Sample output:

```
38    9.966130
40    9.954561
56    9.928231
3     9.913417
1     9.912051
42    9.900780
99    9.664838
93    9.590925
17    9.541304
89    9.344992
Name: 0, dtype: float64
51    9.986446
34    9.984288
14    9.860462
80    9.846139
81    9.664080
21    9.599174
11    9.505443
96    9.491560
43    9.471097
19    9.439773
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```